# Heroku app url made out of random words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I'm new to **rails and heroku**, and this may very well seem like a daft question, if so I appologise, but would appreciate someone at least telling me so.

I've followed the heroku "[getting started](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart)" guide, and managed to deploy a copy of the rails default project. But the url preovided by heroku was `http://radiant-ice-84.heroku.com`, my question is this:

**Does heroku assign a randomly generated url**, or have I done something wrong because I don't recognise `radiant-ice-84`?

Comment: WOW it was a daft question. I found the rename settings within the heroku app detials. Sorry for the stupid question. how do I delete/close this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you closing this question, I would like to say that you in fact could specify the first when you create the app (no need to change again in the setting page) by using:

```
heroku create your-app-name
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't specify a name, Heroku generates one for you. You can change it in your app settings (as you noticed), although a lot of people just buy a domain name and map it to the Heroku-generated name.